# Which function in spark is used to combine two RDDs by keys

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, rdd

Let us say I have the following two RDDs, with the following key-pair values.

```py
rdd1 = [ (key1, [value1, value2]), (key2, [value3, value4]) ]
```

and

```py
rdd2 = [ (key1, [value5, value6]), (key2, [value7]) ]
```

Now, I want to join them by key values, so for example I want to return the following

```py
ret = [ (key1, [value1, value2, value5, value6]), (key2, [value3, value4, value7]) ]
```

How I can I do this, in spark using Python or Scala? One way is to use join, but join would create a tuple inside the tuple. But I want to only have one tuple per key value pair.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would union the two RDDs and to a reduceByKey to merge the values.

```
(rdd1 union rdd2).reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
```

Comment: @Sai Same thing, right? Not sure is meant by "not found"

Comment: Sai's syntax is the one that worked on my architecture. Could be version specific.

Comment: Just to make sure, this is a Scala syntax, not Python, so if you try this in Python, it will throw an error

Answer (score 8):

Just use `join` and then `map` the resulting rdd.

```
rdd1.join(rdd2).map(case (k, (ls, rs)) => (k, ls ++ rs))
```

Comment: I have a rdd of totals and rdd of counts.  How would I join them by the same keys to create an average.  Open to the possibility I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: This should be a separate question, but: if you have `values: RDD[(K, Float)]` and `counts: RDD[(K, Int)]` (map them into this shape if they're not) then you can do `values.join(counts)` to get an `RDD[(K, (Float, Int))]`, `map` away the `K`, and then you can do the average - there's probably a function for this already, but the hard way is `reduce {case ((v1, count1), (v2, count2)) => ((v1 * count1 + v2 * count2) / (count1 + count2), (count1 + count2))}` assuming my maths is right.

Comment: Yeah that's what ended up being the solution.  Thanks!